# How to round the timing with nearest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

For example

Table1

```
time

01:02
00:02
02:37
02:58
....
```

Time format is `HH:MM`

I want to round the timing with nearest value. like

```
01 to 04 means 00 only, 05 to 09 means 05 only, 10 to 14 means 10 only..... 55 to 59 means 55 only, 01:00 to 01:04 means 01:00 only....
```

Expected Output

Table1

```
time

01:00
00:00
02:35
02:55
....
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need Query Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select substring([time], 1, 3) + 
       right(rtrim(('0' + cast(substring([time], 4, 2) / 5 * 5 as CHAR))), 2)
from table1
```

Comment: thank you all are working but when the time is 02:05 means it is showing 02:50 except this all the time are ok, why it is coming like this...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(
    char(5),
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, time) / 5 * 5, 0),
    108
  ) AS time
FROM Table1
```